# which class can be used to create a always free Autonomous database processing instance via the OCI Java Sdk

Tags: oci-java-sdk

I plan to use the Oci java Sdk to create an always free ATP instance in the Oracle OCI environment.
Check with the examples bundled with oci java sdk and API. It lack details for the Always free ATP docs.
like to know

- which class can be used？
- ssh public key required? as from web console, not necessary to give the SSH public key during the creation procedure
- which database edition can be used for Always free?

are the Always free ATP example available?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you check:

https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/java/1.12.1/com/oracle/bmc/database/model/CreateAutonomousDatabaseDetails.Builder.html

The only required parameter to create free is: isFreeTier.

Edition and ssh-public-key is not applicable here.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works, but seems still have to give some more information. i test below code, a new ATP Always free instance can be created.

Comment: CreateAutonomousDatabaseDetails request = CreateAutonomousDatabaseDetails.builder()
       .isFreeTier(true)
       .dataStorageSizeInTBs(1)
      .adminPassword("AvBdDeD#12345")
      .cpuCoreCount(1)
      .dbName("DB"+randomId)
      .displayName("DB"+randomId)
      .compartmentId(compartmentId)
      .build();